# Percentage "%" sign interpreted by AngularJS router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following route in my AngularJS application

```
var accountactivation = {
    name: 'accountactivation',
    url: '/activate/:code',
    templateUrl: 'views/account/activation.html',
    controller: 'AccountActivationController',
    authenticate: false
};
```

Added like this to the router

```
$stateProvider.state(accountactivation)
```

This is a account activation system, where `:code` is the activation code. This code is URL encoded.

**The problem** : sometime `:code` contains `%` character. Then  the navigator is redirected to login instead of displaying the account activation page.

Example of routes

- `http://localhost:9000/#!/activate/c43q6zb2` works correctly
- `http://localhost:9000/#!/activate/c43q6zb2%` is redirected to login (sometimes lead to a blank page)
- `http://localhost:9000/#!/activate/c43q6zb2Fxb%2FxQkjc2qnjc39QEYTQtpVmgWbw2gzNII0z8QRFrRhz%2FNC4LxzqBIYw5tqM9NaY8ejTxIRXQCfTh8hFszyARL%2Ff9MoOp2MvzNulqefVczsuGpZA8RZArQk` doesn't work either

Is it possible to allow angularjs routes to have parameters containing prcentages signs ?

**How I encode my activation key** : For info, I'm using java [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) with UTF-8 encoding charset

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: can you try it with `url: '/activate/:code*'` syntax?

Comment: @aleksey-solovey with this configuration, url never matches, even with `http://localhost:9000/#!/activate/c43q6zb2` url

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

> Because the percent character ( % ) serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as %25 for that octet to be used as data within a URI.

So it seems your URI is invalid with just a %. You need to encode it properly. Either use `%25` so it will decode as %, or remove it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My bad, the example I provided apparently don't reflect correctly what my url-encoding process is giving me. I'm also having issue with the following url : `http://localhost:9000/#!/activate/c43q6zb2Fxb%2FxQkjc2qnjc39QEYTQtpVmgWbw2gzNII0z8QRFrRhz%2FNC4LxzqBIYw5tqM9NaY8ejTxIRXQCfTh8hFszyARL%2Ff9MoOp2MvzNulqefVczsuGpZA8RZArQk`.

Comment: Is it possible that my url-encoding process is not compliant to URL enconding standards ? For info, I'm using [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) with `UTF-8` encoding charset

Comment: @matthiasbe I guess it should be fine. Do you have some guard that maybe doesn't decode correctly the url?

Comment: what are you calling guard ?

Comment: @matthiasbe not sure how they're called in angularjs. What router are you using? I believe ui-router is using route resolvers to prevent accesing a route with invalid data...

Comment: I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). We only have a general redirection that redirects to home or login according to authentication : `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')` in case no URL matches